# Remove colour code special characters from bash file

Tags: bash, sed, tee, ansi-escape

I have a bash script that runs and outputs to a text file however the colour codes it uses are also included what i'd like to know is how to remove them from the file, ie

```
^[[38;1;32mHello^[[39m
^[[38;1;31mUser^[[39m
```

so I just want to be left with Hello and User, so something like sed -r "special characters" from file A save to file B

Comment: For a generic perfect result, you'd have to decode the escape sequences. (is `\033.*[A-Za-z]` enough?) It'd probably by a lot easier to not issue color codes in the first place.

Comment: See answer here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/14707/8696

Answer (score 2):

```
sed 's/\^\[\[[^m]*m//g'
```

remove (all) part of line starting with `^[[` until first `m`

Comment: To make it work for me, I used \x1B instead of \^\[, like that: 's/\x1B\[[^m]*m//g'

Answer (score 0):

Some like this:

```
awk '{sub(/\^\[\[38;1;[0-9][0-9]m/,x);sub(/\^\[\[39m/,x)}1'
Hello
User
```